# Trying to add table and connect it to another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use a FK key to connect the values from one table to a existing table inside SQL

```
CREATE TABLE tblPurchase
(
    PurchaseID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    UserID int,
    PIDSizeID nvarchar(MAX),
    CartAmount money,
    CartDiscount money,
    TotalPayed money,
    PaymentType nvarchar(50),
    PaymentStatus nvarchar(50),
    DateOfPurchese datetime,
    Name nvarchar(200),
    Address nvarchar(MAX),
    PinCode nvarchar(10),
    MobileNumber nvarchar(50),
    
    CONSTRAINT [FK_tblPurchase_ToUser] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [tblUsers] ([UID])
)
```

I have a table `tblUsers` and I have connected other tables to that one with no problem. But this time it says:

> Foreign key 'FK_tblPurchase_ToUser' references invalid table 'tblUsers'.

Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors. Any suggestions? only thing i tried other then checked spelling is refreshing with Ctrl + Shift + R.....

Edit: the column names I use in `tblUsers` are

```
[Uid] [Username] [Password] [Email] [Name] [Usertype]
```

Edit 2: I did a complete new database in SQL Server and just added all the tables again and everything works.... I don't know why SQL Server refuses to add tables from time to time..

Comment: Probably different schemas. `REFERENCES [schema_name].[tblUsers] ([UID])`. Sidenote: tag mysql is probably wrong, it should be SQL Server/T-SQL

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + R just refreshes intellisense, it doesn't make objects that don't current exist suddenly appear. If the error says it doesn't exist it doesn't; you have a typographical error, are using the wrong database/schema or the table really does not exist.

Comment: Re your comment, if you added them all at the same time, you would have added them all in the same schema and same database, one of which was different when you first attempted it.

Comment: show a screenshot of SQLS Management Studio tree view of db schema, clearly showing both tables

Comment: Looks like some significant normalization issues as well as datatype issues. `PIDSizeID nvarchar(MAX)` has a major smell to it.

Comment: I have no idea what happen. before that i tried to add another table that got added but didnt show under "tabels" folder. but still existed and worked when i used select * tblCart. Anyway the new data works and i could add everything without any errors

Comment: probably permission issue tblUsers doesn't have access to the user you logged in, check the schema. and use fully qualified name to reference the foreign key constraints,.

Comment: yeah most likely. off to the next errror! thx for the help

Comment: My guess is you probably had the wrong database selected in SSMS. So say you had the master db selected in SSMS...you tried creating tblPurchase with a FK on tblUsers...but tblUsers doesn't exist in the master database, so it failed. This has happened to me a million times, and I would be that's what this is.

Comment: yes, you are right. I was dead tired that night.